# Global file pointer declaration in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, global

There's some problem with the global file pointer declaration, as a result of which I'm getting a segmentation fault. GDB showed that it occurs specifically at the `fscanf` line in the `sourceToStream` function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#define SOURCE_CODE "source_code.txt"           
#define CHARACTER_STREAM "character_stream.txt"

static FILE* in_fp;
static FILE* out_fp;

void sourceToStream() {
    char buf;

    while(fscanf(in_fp, "%c", &buf) != EOF) {
        if (buf == '\%')
            while(buf!='\n' && buf !='\r' && buf!=EOF)
                fscanf(in_fp, "%c", &buf);

        if(buf != '\n' && buf != '\r' && buf != '\t' && buf != ' ')
            fprintf(out_fp, "%c", buf);
    }
}

int main() {

    in_fp = fopen(SOURCE_CODE, "r");
    out_fp = fopen(CHARACTER_STREAM, "w");

    sourceToStream();

    fclose(in_fp);
    fclose(out_fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `fopen()` succeed ?

Comment: I don't know why Mike deleted his comment, but why don't you check `fopen`'s return value?

Comment: There are two `fscanf`.

Comment: GDB gives the following output after executing the first `fopen()`

`(gdb) p in_fp
$1 = (FILE *) 0x0
(gdb) p *in_fp
Cannot access memory at address 0x0`

Comment: You shouldn't rely on gdb, you must always check the return value of functions that initialise a pointer (like fopen) before trying to use it.

Comment: some error with the source file. Got it, thanks. :-)

Comment: @user42933, then `fopen()` failed as it returns `NULL` on failure. Always check the result of IO operations.

Comment: @Shahbaz - Yes, I probably should have left it... once I realized there was nothing else that could be wrong I deleted it and moved to make it an answer (so I could elaborate on proper error checking)

Comment: `'\%'` is not a valid escape sequence; it should be just `'%'`. `fscanf` with a single `"%c"` is better written as a call to `getc()` -- which returns an `int` result that's set to `EOF` if there's nothing to read. With your current code `buf` will never be equal to `EOF`; `fscanf` indicates end-of-file or error by returning `EOF`, not by storing `EOF` in an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GDB gives the following output after executing the first fopen()
> (gdb) p in_fp $1 = (FILE *) 0x0 
> (gdb) p *in_fp Cannot access memory at address 0x0

That means your files didn't open correctly, or more specifically that source_code.txt wasn't opened for reading.

Since you didn't include a path in your open command, make sure they are in the current working directory (the directory where you are executing your binary from) and make sure you have read/write permissions.

For [`fopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) you can check if the resultant file handle is NULL then print the error message if it was:

```
    in_fp = fopen(SOURCE_CODE, "r");
    if(in_fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open the source");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

If for example, the file doesn't exist you'll get something like:

> Failed to open the source: No such file or directory

Comment: Actually, the file-to-open has to be in the current working directory, which does *not* necessarily coincide with the directory where the code is sitting. +1 otherwise.

Comment: @bitmask - Good point, I made the assumption that source, binary, and text were all just dumped in the same place, but it sure doesn't have to be the case. Updated.

Comment: Why would you refer to cplusplus.com for a C function? Not to mention cplusplus.com is generally considered full of imprecise information and should be avoided anyway.

Comment: @Shahbaz - a couple friends of mine (who are begining coding) have told me they find it easier to read, than the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and like the fact that it has examples for most everything, where as man pages are hit or miss. So when the information is correct I tend to link to those... and I do believe the information is correct for C and in general on the `fopen()` cplusplus.com page

Comment: `return EXIT_FAILURE;` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` would make more sense than `return -1;`

Comment: @KeithThompson - `would make more sense` I guess that would depend on what the caller was expecting... but I will agree that it's much more generically accepted. Updated that.